# Content out of window

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website, and it should be responsive, but my whole content instead, in some screens is out of the window's width. This shouldn't happen.

This is the `HTML` code for my `main div` which contains also a `container` `div` which is inside each `<section>`:

```
<div id="main">

        <!-- Navigation Bar -->
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <!-- Code cut -->
        </div>
        <!-- / Navigation Bar -->

            <!-- Intro -->
                <section id="top" class="one dark cover">
                    <div class="container">

                        <header>
                            <!-- Code cut -->
                        </header>   
                    </div>
```

What should the CSS look like to make it responsive so that it won't go outside the window's width but (for example) collapsing the table datas instead?  Let me know what you think would be better to solve this issue.

Every item of the content (such as image, countdown, tables..) is out of the window's width.

Here is the most relevant CSS:

Containers:

```
/* Containers */

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1750px;
    min-width: 1400px;
}

.container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 1050px;
}

.container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 700px;
}

.container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 350px;
}

.container {
    width: 1400px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1880px) {

    .container.\31 25\25 {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1500px;
        min-width: 1200px;
    }

    .container.\37 5\25 {
        width: 900px;
    }

    .container.\35 0\25 {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .container.\32 5\25 {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .container {
        width: 1200px;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1620px) {

    .container.\31 25\25 {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        min-width: 960px;
    }

    .container.\37 5\25 {
        width: 720px;
    }

    .container.\35 0\25 {
        width: 480px;
    }

    .container.\32 5\25 {
        width: 240px;
    }

    .container {
        width: 960px;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1320px) {

    .container.\31 25\25 {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 125%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .container.\37 5\25 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .container.\35 0\25 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .container.\32 5\25 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

    .container.\31 25\25 {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 125%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .container.\37 5\25 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .container.\35 0\25 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .container.\32 5\25 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

    .container.\31 25\25 {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 125%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    .container.\37 5\25 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .container.\35 0\25 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .container.\32 5\25 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

}
```

Main:

```
/* The main content */

.main-content {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
max-width: 600px;
padding-top: 40px;
margin: 0 0 40px 260px;
}
```

For reference, here is the site: http://infntest.altervista.org/index.html.

Comment: is the left margin intended? I can see you are using bootstrap grid pretty wrong, please consult [bootstrap grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: You first need to correct some errors shown in the inspector before anyone can give a proper solution to your problem as some CSS is being ignored. `<style>` and `</style>` inside your main `<style>` (error 'selector expected...'). You cannot simply ignore errors like that.

Comment: Yes, I surely have some errors in it, I guess it's in the bootstrap template, any ideas?

Comment: Question updated @RenevanderLende

Comment: Hi there. I don't this question meets the _Stack Overflow_ guidelines presently, as it refers readers to a website that needs fixing. Once you have fixed that website, the question will no longer be useful for future readers, since the evidence of the problem will have disappeared at the external link. Would you add the missing CSS to this question, and remove the link? Thanks! (I'll happily undownvote if you are able to do so).

Comment: Hey @halfer I surely can, but the fact is I don't know where the right issue/problem is, I'd be really happy to report the CSS property fixed in the solution once solved, but at this time I might be able just to report you some css about.. the container or something else I don't really know, so I thought it would have been a lot better to give you the link and let you use the Inspect Element panel to find the CSS way faster, by the way let me know if you need something particular instead, I'll edit my question right away with the necessary code!

Comment: If people need to go to your site, it's off-topic in my opinion, for the reasons I've outlined (and also because links have quite a high breakage rate). One approach to tackle this is to try to replicate the problem using a live JS site e.g. JS Fiddle, and that way you'll have the smallest CSS that still exhibits the problem, and it can easily be pasted here.

Comment: From the _Meta_ site (about how _Stack Overflow_ works), this is [useful reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260565/how-strict-should-we-be-when-enforcing-the-no-external-sites-or-the-no-code) and definitely [this too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @halfer I've edited my question with the main HTML content, that might surely help to understand which is the main container, tell me if CSS is needed too

Comment: Well, I would _imagine_ the CSS is needed. Gvidas seems to have referred to it, and he or she presumably would not have given an answer if they did not have access to it. (If you have a large amount of CSS, then this is where the advice about cutting down the problem to the smallest possible case is useful, see the answer in the second link above).

Comment: Yes, asked that just to take some time to find it out, I've edited my question with the most relevant part of the CSS: containers and main @halfer

Comment: Alright, that looks much more answerable. _Ideally_ the link would be removed as well, but I don't know how strictly that is enforced, and at least now readers have a chance to understand the question in the future, if the link does break. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Thank you too for yours and to have undownvoted the question! Now let's see if we can get some replies about the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Bootstrap. It has a class `table-responsive` that will resolve your issue.

Responsive tables are a pain.

I would go with div's instead and according to viewport change the properties of those divs accordingly.

Have a look at http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/raXdwZ for a Bootstrap implementation or https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php for a responsive table example.

Answer (score 0):

From your link provided i can see that your whole `.container` class is out of the screen. Try to add `box-sizing: border-box;` css property to your `.container` class and this should fix your issue.

`box-sizing: border-box;` css property includes paddings and borders to width calculation, so then you write `width:100%; padding-left:15px;` you have 100%-15px of content and 15px of padding instead of 100% content and additional 15px padding. [more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out as soon as I am back home, should give you some responses in 2/3 hours

Comment: Mmmmm doesn't seem to work, but where should I edit it precisely? I did edit the .container class CSS properties with that

Answer (score 0):

use footable , it is useful for designing responsive tables

http://fooplugins.com/plugins/footable-jquery/